# How can I change the drupal form action based on Radio button selected?

Tags: 7, forms

I have developed a custom form in my module. Now I have to change the form action based on radio button selected. Suppose if I have 3 radio buttons saying
1. ABC
2. DEF
3. XYZ

If i select ABC and submit form, my result should display on www.domainname.com/abc

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the Form action in submit function

```
    function your_form_name_submit($form,&$form_state){
          if($form_state['values']['radion_button_name'] == 'abc') {
         $form_state['redirect'] = url('path/to/redirect');
        }
    else{
       $form_state['redirect'] = url('path/to/redirect');
     }
}
```

hope this will help you!!

Comment: Would be nice if you wold mention that it will not change form's action in HTML sense, only the page user sees at the end.

Answer (score 1):

There may be following options to change the form action based on radio option selection.

**1. Using ajax callback**

Create menu item

```
/**
 * Implements hook_init().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_menu(){
  $items = array();
  $items['stack-exchange'] = array(
    'title' => 'Stack exchange',
    'description' => 'Stack exchange.',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('stack_exchange_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  return $items;
}

// form callback
function stack_exchange_form($form, &$form_state){
  $form = array();
  $options = array('abc' => t('ABC'), 'def' => t('DEF'), 'xyz' => t('XYZ'));

   $form['submitto'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => t('Submit to'),
    '#options' => $options,
    '#description' => t('Select a option to submit the form to specific location.'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'alter_form_action',
    ),
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit')
  );
  return $form;
}

// ajax call back
function alter_form_action($form, $form_state){
  $commands = array();
  $action = $form_state['values']['submitto'];
  switch($action){
    case "abc":
      $submit_to = 'your-path/' . $action;
      break;
    case "def":
      $submit_to = 'your-other-path/' . $action;
      break;
    case "xyz":
      $submit_to = 'your-again-other-path/' . $action;
      break;
  }
  $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('form#stack-exchange','attr', array('action', $submit_to));
  return array('#type' => 'ajax','#commands' => $commands);
}
```

**2. Using jquery**

```
// attach js file in from callback
$form['#attached']['js'] = array(
    drupal_get_path('module', 'dev') . '/js/stack_exchange_form.js'
  );
```

and put following js code into

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.YOUR_MODULE = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $("form#stack-exchange-form input[name=submitto]:radio").change(function () {
        var action = $(this).val();
        var submit_to = '';
        switch(action){
          case "abc":
            submit_to = 'your-path/' + action;
            break;
          case "def":
            submit_to = 'your-other-path/' + action;
            break;
          case "xyz":
            submit_to = 'your-again-other-path/' + action;
            break;
        }
        $('form#stack-exchange-form').attr('action', submit_to);
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Note: you need to change the hook name and element selector accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can do this stuff in your form submit.

```
function yourmodule_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
 // do your submit stuff
 if($form_state['values']['radion_button_name'] == 'abc') {
   drupal_goto('abc path');
 } else if ($form_state['values']['radion_button_name'] == 'efg') {
   drupal_goto('efg path');
 } else {
   drupal_goto('default path');
 }
}
```

Comment: I believe `form_state` should be preferred

Answer (score 0):

**You can apply this code it will work for you:**

```
 <?php

function formalter_menu() {
$items = array();

$items['examples/form-example'] = array( //this creates a URL that will call this form at "examples/form-example"
'title' => 'Example Form', //page title
'description' => 'A form to mess around with.',
'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', //this is the function that will be called when the page is accessed.  for a form, use drupal_get_form
'page arguments' => array('formalter_form'), //put the name of the form here
'access callback' => TRUE
);

return $items;
}

function formalter_form($form, &$form_state) {

$form['price'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield', //you can find a list of available types in the form api
'#title' => 'What is Your Price?',
'#size' => 10,
'#maxlength' => 10,
'#required' => TRUE, //make this field required 
);
$form['topic'] = array(

 '#type' => 'radios',
 '#title' => t('Topic'),
 '#options' =>          array('Movie'=>t('Movie'),'Songs'=>t('Songs'),'Ads'=>t('Ads'),'Tv  

Serials'=>t('Tv Serials'),'Others'=>t('Others')),
    );
  $form['submit_button'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => t('Click Here!'),
  );

  return $form;
 }

 function formalter_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
 // dpm($form);
//dpm($form_state);
  if($form_state['values']['topic'] == "Movie")
   {
  $form_state['redirect'] = url('http://www.google.com');
     }
    else{
      $form_state['redirect'] = url('http://www.yahoo.com');
      }
  }

  function formalter_form_submit($form, &$form_state)
{
drupal_set_message('warning',"Thanks for submitting the form");

  }

 ?>
```